# Like/Up Vote Button With Vue.Js, axios And Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.5

I am trying to create a like button for a recipe page on my site using Vue. 
I am a begginer with vue and combining it with laravel, so i cant find the problem here. 
Few things to note about what i am doing.

1. I dont want the option to like/ up vote a recipe be open just to registered users.
2. I know that after a page refresh(using the code i have now), that same person can click it again. My logic is that i dont think a person would do such a thing, esspecialy not the crowd my site refers to, so it fine by me.

well, here is the code i have done so far.

```
 <like :recipe="{{$recipe}}" inline-template>
    <div>
       <button class="button is-medium" @click="iLikeIt":disabled="disabled" >Like</button>
       <button class="button is-medium fa fa-thumbs-up"  v-text="like"></button>
    </div>
 </like>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    export default{
        props:['recipe'],

        data(){
            return{
            like:0,
            disabled:false
            }
        },

        methods:{
            iLikeIt(){
                   this.like++;
                   this.disabled=true;
                    axios.post('/likes/'+this.recipe.id, {
                        likes: this.like,
                        id:this.recipe.id
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Here are the routes:

```
Route::post('/likes/{id}','RecipesController@likes');
```

And this is the likes function:

```
public function likes(Request $request,$id){
 if (request()->expectsJson()) {
    $recipe=Recipe::find($id);
    $recipe->likes=$request->likes;
       return $recipe;
    }
}
```

Edit:
I of course must add, as per the comments:
The increments works fone, and the disabeling of the button also works.
What does not work is the persistend and incrementing on the DB table.
The response i get in the console is this:

```
    `{data: " status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…},

    ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
    data
    :
    "{"likes":1,"id":117}"

    method
    :
    "post"

    "/likes/117"

    request
    :
    XMLHttpRequest
 {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload}
    status
    :
    200
    statusText
    :
    "OK"
    __proto__
    :
    Object`
```

That's about it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague: **what exactly is broken**? Is the like count not increasing as you expected? Or is the server not updating the like count in the table properly? Check your browser console, is the request being sent and received properly? What `response` do you receive when the request promise is resolved?

Comment: If you don't want unregistered users to be able to vote simply wrap your component with an `Auth::check()` if statement. Or create a second component withint your else statement with different options. `"My logic is that i dont think a person would do such a thing"` you do not want to make this assumption.

Comment: @Terry Please look at the updated question.

Comment: @Stephan-v I DO want unregistred people to be able to like it.

Comment: @GabMic so what is the problem? That is default behavior unless you have specified an `Auth::check()` somewhere else or locked down the route.

Comment: @Stephan-v As i sat to Terry here, the problem is that it does not persist to the database. I have updated the question, can you have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. 
I have a middleware('auth') preventing the request and response the proper data. 
Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your Laravel model code

```
public function likes($id){
    if (request()->expectsJson()) {
        $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
        $recipe->likes++;
        $recipe->save();
        return $recipe;
    }
}
```

You forgot to call `save()` to ensure the updated value gets pushed to the database. I also changed it from receiving a value to incrementing on call as that prevents collision and overwrite issues.

Comment: Hi, i am now getting this:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
`